# Select duplicated values from one column and get there value in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates

I have a table with 2 columns like this:

```
+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B |
+----------+----------+
|      123 |    ABC   |
|      123 |    XYC   |
|      123 |    FGH   |
|      145 |    QWE   |
|      147 |    YUI   |
+----------+----------+
```

I want to select all values from table but view it - like this:

```
+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| Column A | value 1 | value 2 | value 3  |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+
|      123 | ABC     | XYC     | FGH      |
|      145 | QWE     |         |          |
|      147 | YUI     |         |          |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple columns where there are multiple values?

Comment: Look into `PIVOT`.

Comment: @Nick no i all need is to select all values in table but view all duplicated rows beside each other only view it not create columns

Comment: @daShier i will check it :)

Comment: @M.Zaky Give it a shot, then if you get stuck, show what your query looks like and what is the result you got vs. what you want. I'm sure someone will get you past that.

Comment: Rows in sql tables have no order , so it's meaningless to talk about values 1, 2, and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not trying to create extra columns in your output, you can simply use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with the separator of your choice. For example:

```
SELECT `Column A`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(`Column B` SEPARATOR ' | ') AS `Values`
FROM table1
GROUP BY `Column A`
```

Output:

```
Column A    Values
123         ABC | XYC | FGH
145         QWE
147         YUI
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/es1dJTxtwpjorXNuCfvxUP/0)

Comment: i used this '|' for only differentiate between every result but on DB i don't have this '|'  and i will update my question also to be clear :)

Comment: @M.Zaky I understand, if you look at the `GROUP_CONCAT` part of the query, that is where I have inserted the `|`. If you don't want a `|`, you can use something else e.g. `,`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how are you going to execute the query? but if you can manage to create dynamic SQL query string to find all duplicates rows and insert each row into a temp table and other values (unique) into a separate temp table. Then create another query to join all temp tables (with duplicate) value into a new data set, union all of them with the (unique) data set.

It may be a long and not a good solution but here's my experiment:

1. Insert all duplicates rows into #temp tables (3 rows= 3 #temp tables)

   ```
   SELECT Id,Name 
   INTO #temp1 
   FROM TestTable 
   WHERE Name='ABC'
   ```

   SELECT Id,Name 
   INTO #temp2
   FROM TestTable 
   WHERE Name='XYC'

   SELECT Id,Name 
   INTO #temp3
   FROM TestTable 
   WHERE Name='FGH'
2. Insert all unique rows into single #temptable

   ```
   SELECT Id,Name
   INTO #temp4
   FROM TestTable
   WHERE Id!=123
   ```
3. Query

   ```
   SELECT t1.Id,t1.Name as Value1,t2.Name as Value2,t3.Name as Value3
   FROM #temp1 t1
   INNER JOIN #temp2 t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id
   INNER JOIN #temp3 t3 on t1.Id=t3.Id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t4.Id,t4.Name as Value1,null as Value2,null as Value3
   FROM #temp4 t4
   ```
4. Result
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want three different columns, you can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select a,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then b end) as b_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then b end) as b_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then b end) as b_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by a;
```

Comment: But it's not ordered by b